# regular expression in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am unable to search for the following text in notepad++, I am trying to use regular expression.

```
Insert into SOMETABLE (COULMN1,COULMN2,COULMN3,COULMN4,COULMN5,COULMN6) values ('ANYTHING','ANYTHING',to_date('30-APR-13 18:51:41','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'ANYTHING',to_date('30-APR-13 18:51:41','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'ANYTHING');
```

I am trying to search `to_date('30-APR-13 18:51:41','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS')` from the above line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match everything from `to_date(` up to the closest `)`, search for

```
to_date\([^)]*\)
```

(using the Perl regex option).

Explanation: `[^)]*` matches any number of characters except `)`.